# Can I create an NSURL that refers to in-memory NSData?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdata, nsurl

[The docs for `NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state that:

> An NSURL object represents a URL that can potentially contain the
>   location of a resource on a remote server, the path of a local file on
>   disk, or even ***an arbitrary piece of encoded data*.**

I have a blob of in-memory data that I'd like to hand to a library that wants to load a resource via an `NSURL`. Sure, I can first write this `NSData` to a temp file and then create a `file://` `NSURL` from that, but I'd prefer to have the URL point directly to the buffer that I already have present in memory.

The docs quoted above seem to suggest this is possible, but I can't find any hint of how to accomplish it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe it means you can give it a Data URI? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: If I have a URL like - https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=QRUPRC%3A it will return a barcode image to me, but that image is not really stored physically in google's file server - it is generated.   I think that is what it means

Comment: So basically you want `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURLHere]` to give the data that you already have in RAM instead of reading it from a file?

Comment: The documentation for `NSData` makes a few references to `data://` as a supported URL protocol, but I can't find any documentation for exactly how it works. Most likely it's just the data as a hex string?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`NSURL` supports the data:// URL-Scheme ([RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)).
This scheme allows you to build URLs in the form of

```
data://data:MIME-Type;base64,<data>
```

A working Cocoa example would be:

```
NSImage* img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"img"];
NSData* imgData = [img TIFFRepresentation];
NSString* dataFormatString = @"data:image/png;base64,%@";
NSString* dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:dataFormatString, [imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
NSURL* dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
```

Passing around large binary blobs with data URLs might be a bit inefficient due to the nature of base64 encoding.

You could also implement a custom [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that specifically deals with your data.
Apple has some sample code that uses a custom protocol to pass around image objects: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SpecialPictureProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003816

Comment: Another example: `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];` gives you `@"hello world"`. Not too inefficient, it only 4 extra bytes compared to ASCII.

Comment: Thanks. The `data:` protocol is definitely functional for smaller buffers (if anyone's interested I wrote a tiny protocol that does it here: https://github.com/bzotto/NSURL-DataAdditions). The custom `NSURLProtocol` way is probably the "best" answer here, because the first option would be hugely wasteful in terms of memory (and requires a bunch of encoding) for anything nontrivial.

Comment: I attempted to use this logic to create a NSURL with MP4 video data inline and then play that with AVFoundation. A movie file will not load using this approach, perhaps the NSURLProtocol would be more successful.

Answer (score 6):

What you are missing is the NSURLProtocol class. Takes about three dozen lines of code, and any code that handles URLs properly can access your in-memory data. Read the documentation, it's not difficult and there is sample code available.

Unfortunately there are some APIs that take an NSURL as a parameter, but can only handle file URLs.