# Play a video stored using NSDataAsset (Xcode xcassets)

Tags: ios, asset-catalog, app-thinning

I am trying to use Apple [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) feature (available from iOS 9) that let you differentiate resources based on device architecture and features. In my case what I would like to do is to have a different video file in the application bundle (in `.mp4` format) one for the iPhone and one for the iPad using Xcode `.xcassets` `Data Set`.

To retrieve a file from a `.xcassets` `Data Set` Apple provides the `NSDataAsset` class, but: since `AVPlayer` needs a `URL` to play a video and `NSDataAsset` only provides its contents using `Data` format, I'm unable to play the video.

What I would like to do is to retrive the `NSDataAsset` `.data` `URL`. Is it possible?

Comment: You may look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644193/can-i-create-an-nsurl-that-refers-to-in-memory-nsdata

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
NSDataAsset *videosDataAsset = [[NSDataAsset alloc] initWithName:@"AssetName"];
NSData *data = videosDataAsset.data;
NSString *filename = @"FileToSaveInto.mp4";
NSURL *URL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

if ([data writeToURL:URL atomically:YES]) {
    // run player
}
```